# Exposed filters in views with Ajax turned on doesn't generate url

Tags: 8, views

When using an exposed filter in a view while turning on Ajax doesn't generate a unique url.

**Page with Ajax off**

> nl/finder?product%5B284%5D=284&industry%5B269%5D=269&country%5B288%5D=288&country%5B290%5D=290

**Page with Ajax on**

> nl/finder#

Is this normal behavior of drupal or is there some setting i'm missing? I need to link to the page with some filters preset.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Views Ajax history](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_ajax_history) to accomplish what you are asking. There are a couple of bugs when using supporting modules such as Views Infinite Scroll, but for the most part this allows you to keep browser history as you add filters and change pages, allowing your user to use the forward and back buttons in their browser.

Comment: Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

That is how Ajax is supposed to work, it doesn't refresh the page so it can't change the URL.

But the Exposed filter links should work even with Ajax enabled. Ajax is there just to speed things up, it doesn't provide vital structure.

If you need to provide ready-made Exposed filter links you can add them manually, in Views header, on other pages, or create menus of them. You could even do some Views Contextual filter magic with Summaries to provide the link filter combinations.